# How can I found out if an infusionsoft contact has a specific tag id

Tags: php, tags

Does anyone have an example of php code to check to see if an Infusionsoft contact has a specific tag?  I am using the following code to insert into Infusionsoft Campaign Builder image feature.  The code is a file called buspass.php.  After I scanned the image with the applied code it does not display the "Display the Route #'s" as echoed with the "If" statements.  After the scan the image looks like this: [image after QR Scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQrGr.jpg)

Here's what I have:

```
<html>
<code>

  <p><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;" src="https://d1yoaun8syyxxt.cloudfront.net/ib945-9ac2eb8c510b-4ac6-b282-bcd4552812f1-v2" alt="TOPA LOGO" width="80%" /></p>

<?php
require_once("isdk.php");
$app = new iSDK;

// Establish Connnection
if ($app->cfgCon("ib945"));

// Confirm Connection with Date Display
date_default_timezone_set("America/Phoenix");
echo "<div align='center'><h2>Scanned on " . $currentDate = 
date("Y/m/d @ h:i:sa") . "<br/></h2></div>";

echo "<div align='center'><img src='https://d1yoaun8syyxxt.cloudfront.net/ib945-321c85f8-dafe-45a1-9388-ef7fb6b7b4ec-v2'/></div>";

// Call Infusiosoft Contact Information
$Id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$fname = $_REQUEST['fname'];
$lname = $_REQUEST['lname'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$phone1 = $_REQUEST['phone1'];
$sfname1 = $_REQUEST['sfname1'];
$slname1 = $_REQUEST['slname1'];
$sfname2 = $_REQUEST['sfname2'];
$slname2 = $_REQUEST['slname2'];
$sfname3 = $_REQUEST['sfname3'];
$slname3 = $_REQUEST['slname3'];
$sfname4 = $_REQUEST['sfname4'];
$slname4 = $_REQUEST['slname4'];
$sfname5 = $_REQUEST['sfname5'];
$slname5 = $_REQUEST['slname5'];
$sfname6 = $_REQUEST['sfname6'];
$slname6 = $_REQUEST['slname6'];

//Display Parent/Guardian Information
echo "<div align='center'><h1><u>PARENT/GUARDIAN INFORMATION:</u> 
<br/><br/>
<div align='left'>Contact ID: $Id<br/>
Name: $fname $lname<br/>
Email: $email<br/>
Phone: $phone1<br/></h1></div>";

//Display Scholar Names
echo strtoupper ("<div align='center'><h1><u>BUS RIDER SCHOLAR 
NAME(S):</u></h1></div>
<div align='left'><strong><font size='24'>$sfname1 
$slname1<br/>$sfname2 $slname2<br/>$sfname3 $slname3<br/>$sfname4 
$slname4<br/>$sfname5 $slname5<br/>$sfname6 $slname6</strong> 
</div>");

//Display Route #'s
If($tagId == 1184 || $tagId == 1192) {
echo 'Route #1';
}
If($tagId == 1182 || $tagId == 1194) {
echo 'Route #2';
}
If($tagId == 1186 || $tagId == 1196) {
echo 'Route #3';
}

?>

<p><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;" src="https://d1yoaun8syyxxt.cloudfront.net/ib945-585a8b93-7096-4240-b543-e40ffecc5699-v2" alt="Thumbs Up" width="60%" />

</code>
</html>
```

Comment: have you **tried** anything **yourself** so far?

Comment: I received negative marks by 7 people because I asked a very specific question...  Why???  The following question is as specific as possible: Does anyone have an example of php code to check to see if an Infusionsoft contact has a specific tag?  Tell me what else do you need to go along with this question.

Comment: @MatthewCaraway  Most people are not wiling to do your work for you. Your question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. 
Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: what's needed? for one: **samples of your effort** - we're here to *help* you, not do your job for you. if you don't do anything yourself, why should we? also: reading and understanding the rules about what and how to post should be beneficial.

Comment: I have updated my question with an attempt to what I have tried.

Comment: hint: `($tagId == 1184 || 1192)`does not work that way. you need to use `($tagId == 1184 || $tagId ==1192)` also your question still doesn't include what exactly your problem is.

Comment: Hi Franz, I think I have addressed all of the concerns in which you are looking for.  Can you take another look and see what I may be missing in the complete code.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is in the QR Scan, but it looks like you are passing the information for the contact and other individuals in the URL, is that correct? It also looks like you are using the iSDK. If you have the iSDK files you should be able to use something like this:

If you need to get the contact information:

```
    $app = new iSDK;
    if (!$app->cfgCon("CONNNAME")) 
    exit; 
    $returnFields = array('Email', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Company');
    $conDat = $app->dsLoad("Contact", $contact_id, $returnFields);
    if (isset($conDat['Email'])){
     $email = $conDat['Email'];
    }
    if (isset($conDat['FirstName'])){
     $FirstName = $conDat['FirstName'];
    }
    if (isset($conDat['LastName'])){
     $LastName = $conDat['LastName'];
    }
    if (isset($conDat['Company'])){
     $Company = $conDat['Company'];
    }
```

You can of course change the fields to what you need...

To get tags:

```
    $app = new iSDK;
    if (!$app->cfgCon("CONNNAME")) 
    exit;
    $fields = array('Id', 'Groups');
    $results = $app->loadCon($contact_id,$fields);
    $BufferTEXT = "0,".$results['Groups'];
    switch (true) {
     case strpos($BufferTEXT,'1184') || strpos($BufferTEXT,'1192'): 
      echo 'Route #1';
      break;
     case strpos($BufferTEXT,'1182') || strpos($BufferTEXT,'1194'): 
      echo 'Route #1';
      break;
     case strpos($BufferTEXT,'1186') || strpos($BufferTEXT,'1196'): 
      echo 'Route #1';
      break;
     default:
      echo 'No Assigned Route';
      break;
    }
```

The reason I use the $BufferTEXT, is because if your tag is the first one the strpos function won't catch it. So adding a 0, to the beginning of the array fixed it for me.

I did not test the code, I have used similar code in the past and it worked for me. I hope this points you in the right direction.

I actually test this code and it works, assuming you are actually connecting using your connection string, not just putting your application Id in the cfgCon and also that all the names and contactId is coming into the URL for the QR Code:

```
    <html>
    <code>

     <p><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;" src="https://d1yoaun8syyxxt.cloudfront.net/ib945-9ac2eb8c510b-4ac6-b282-bcd4552812f1-v2" alt="TOPA LOGO" width="80%" /></p>

    <?php


  include 'isdk.php';
  $apiKey = 'YOURAPIKEY';
  $secret = 'YOURSECRETKEY';
  $app = new iSDK;
  //I am assuming you have set up the connection string???
  if (!$app->cfgCon("ib945")) 
  exit;

    // Confirm Connection with Date Display
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Phoenix");
    echo "<div align='center'><h2>Scanned on " . $currentDate = 
    date("Y/m/d @ h:i:sa") . "<br/></h2></div>";

    echo "<div align='center'><img src='https://d1yoaun8syyxxt.cloudfront.net/ib945-321c85f8-dafe-45a1-9388-ef7fb6b7b4ec-v2'/></div>";

    // Call Infusionsoft Contact Information
    // I am assuming that you are passing this data in the url???
    $Id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $fname = $_REQUEST['fname'];
    $lname = $_REQUEST['lname'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $phone1 = $_REQUEST['phone1'];
    $sfname1 = $_REQUEST['sfname1'];
    $slname1 = $_REQUEST['slname1'];
    $sfname2 = $_REQUEST['sfname2'];
    $slname2 = $_REQUEST['slname2'];
    $sfname3 = $_REQUEST['sfname3'];
    $slname3 = $_REQUEST['slname3'];
    $sfname4 = $_REQUEST['sfname4'];
    $slname4 = $_REQUEST['slname4'];
    $sfname5 = $_REQUEST['sfname5'];
    $slname5 = $_REQUEST['slname5'];
    $sfname6 = $_REQUEST['sfname6'];
    $slname6 = $_REQUEST['slname6'];

    //Display Parent/Guardian Information
    echo "<div align='center'><h1><u>PARENT/GUARDIAN INFORMATION:</u> 
    <br/><br/>
    <div align='left'>Contact ID: $Id<br/>
    Name: $fname $lname<br/>
    Email: $email<br/>
    Phone: $phone1<br/></h1></div>";

    //Display Scholar Names
    echo strtoupper ("<div align='center'><h1><u>BUS RIDER SCHOLAR 
    NAME(S):</u></h1></div>
    <div align='left'><strong><font size='24'>$sfname1 
    $slname1<br/>$sfname2 $slname2<br/>$sfname3 $slname3<br/>$sfname4 
    $slname4<br/>$sfname5 $slname5<br/>$sfname6 $slname6</strong> 
    </div>");
    //Display Route #'s

    $fields = array('Id', 'Groups');
    $results = $app->loadCon($Id,$fields);
    $BufferTEXT = "0,".$results['Groups'];

    switch (true) {
     case strpos($BufferTEXT,'1184') || strpos($BufferTEXT,'1192'): 
      echo 'Route #1';
      break;
     case strpos($BufferTEXT,'1182') || strpos($BufferTEXT,'1194'): 
      echo 'Route #2';
      break;
     case strpos($BufferTEXT,'1186') || strpos($BufferTEXT,'1196'): 
      echo 'Route #3';
      break;
     default:
      echo 'No Assigned Route';
      break;
    }

    ?>

    <p><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;" src="https://d1yoaun8syyxxt.cloudfront.net/ib945-585a8b93-7096-4240-b543-e40ffecc5699-v2" alt="Thumbs Up" width="60%" />

    </code>
    </html>
```